# How to remove margin from last child in this situation?

Tags: html, css, sass

How can I remove for example *margin* from the last **content__graph-item** in this situatation?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="content__graph-item"></div>
  </td>
   <td>
    <div class="content__graph-item"></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't by pure CSS, but you can by detecting the last cell in a row, in case they all contain the same class. `td:last-child .content__graph-item {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table tr > td:last-child .content__graph-item{
   margin:0px;
}
```

In this case, it is recommended to give a class name to the table.

Answer (score 1):

It is the td that is the last child so try

```
td:last-child .content__graph-item
```